# How to send the ESC signal to vim when my esc key doesn't work?

Tags: vim

I'm having a problem with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key when I want to return to the interactive mode from the insert mode. Is there exist another key used to release the insert mode.

Comment: Press control `[`

Comment: Quite a few suggestions over on http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/300/9708 too.

Comment: new Macbook Pro? <grin>

Comment: no, thinkpad x1 carbon

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro.  If you happen to be on a MacBook, press `control+c` to exit insert mode.  And the esc-not-working problem on macOS is probably caused by a frozen Siri, if not caused by hardware issue. Just go to Activity Monitor to force quit Siri, then you might solve the esc problem completely. ^_^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existing solutions notwithstanding, the *conventional* solution in Vim is to remap keys in your `.vimrc` configuration. In fact, many Vim users have an easier reachable key remapped to <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Popular choices are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, or <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>, etc.

To enable this, just put something like the following into your `.vimrc` and reload it/restart Vim:

```
" Shift-Enter
inoremap <S-CR> <Esc>
" Double-j
inoremap jj <Esc>
```

[More information and alternatives](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key)

Comment: Eyup, that's the Vim way.  Another common way promoted by *Learn Vim the Hard Way* (book) is `inoremap jk <Esc>`

Comment: This is a nice solution, but what is the problem to use only Ctrl+Enter+j?

Comment: @SandraRoss You can really use any key combination you fancy (though beware that some, e.g. Ctrl-Enter, don’t work on macOS). That said, Ctrl+Enter+j strikes me as more difficult to type, and I honestly don’t know whether you can even configure three-key combinations with two non-modifier keys (Enter, j) in Vim.

Comment: Ok, I undertand. In fact, Ctrl+Enter+jj doesn't work for me, because, indeed, I use macos X. At least, could you tell me what I have to enter for just Ctrl+j.

Comment: @SandraRoss For that, `inoremap <C-j> <Esc>` should work. :-)

Comment: Great! It works well with `Ctrl+j`, and It's much more easier than `Esc`

Answer (score 75):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> sends the same character to the terminal as the physical <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.  The latter is simply a shortcut for the former, generally.

Comment: I once had a real vt220 terminal, and its keyboard does not have a `Escape` key. Pressing `Ctrl+[` was the _only_ way to generate `Escape`.

Answer (score 31):

You could try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, that works for me and is in my opinion easier than <kbd>ESC</kbd>. However I am not sure if it is enabled by default.

Comment: CTRL-C is ASCII `0x03`, sends SIGINT to the shell -- isn't the same as ESC.

Comment: @cat It works basically the same in vim though. I am always using Ctrl-C instead of Esc

Comment: @ErikW i'm 99% sure that's because vim traps and handles sigint though

Comment: @cat That is probably true, but it still is a good solution since it handles it as ESC (enter normal mode)

Comment: @ErikW no, you need to install a handler / trap for your process yourself, you do not get it for free

Comment: @cat: You do get it for free, because vim has that handler in place. You don't have to do anything yourself. This answer works out of the box; I just tried it. Does it work _in general_ for any application? No, but that's not what was asked for.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  It wasn't clear to me this question is supposed to be *specific* to vim and not all terminal console applications in Unix and Linux.

Comment: @cat: Really? The title is _"How to send the ESC signal to vim when my esc key doesn't work?"_, the only tag is [tag:vim], and the problem described in the question is about escaping Vim's insertion mode. Here is the summarising part of the question: _"Is there exist another key used to release the insert mode."_ If that's not specific to Vim and its insert mode, then I don't know what is!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, when I saw the title initially, it was "Another key used for Esc" and the question didn't look specific to `vim` at at all. sorry! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: So this was the only solution that worked for me on iterm2 on mac inside a tmux session. Hopefully that will help people stuck like I was.. nobody wants to have to kill a session off..

Comment: This is the only option that worked for me in Intellij.

Comment: It works for web browsers.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to be able to use a single key, as a pure *nix solution (without Vim mappings) you could define another key as <kbd>Esc</kbd>.  Just like Emacs users remap <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> some Vim users (me included) remap <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd>.  This works for any *nix using X11.

Use `xev -event keyboard` (and then press <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>) to get the keycode for the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key (for me it is keycode 66).  Then you can use `xmodmap` to remap the key:

```
xmodmap -e 'remove Lock = Caps_Lock' -e 'keycode 66 = Escape'
```

---

To get this at login you can add the `xmodmap` expressions to `~/.Xmodmap` as follows:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keycode 66 = Escape
```

Although for the second part YMMV, since not all display managers run `~/.Xmodmap`.  You may need to add `xmodmap .Xmodmap` to `.xinitrc` on some of them.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean. I've seen that earlier this week

Comment: I would do that, but I use CapsLock as my Compose key (:

Answer (score 2):

Terminal emulators send an ESC code also when you press:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> I like this one as you can use one hand only to press it.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> followed by any other key. For example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>l</kbd> will exit insert mode and move the cursor at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue in Siri that prevents some systems from reading ESC.

If that's the case, the following command should fix it:

```
killall Siri
```

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

Is enabled by default. No need to configure any settings.

You will move to normal mode, where you can do `:q! or :wq`.

Comment: `Ctrl+F2` may send an escape, but it will also send other things.